# How to add custom css in Cognos?

Tags: css, business-intelligence, cognos

I have created some cognos reports and i want to override the global design in some of them (prompt pages and report pages).

I would like to know if it is possible to load different custom css files per report.

If this is not possible then how can i load a global custom css together with the global cognos css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an HTML Item with something like

```html
<link href="http://your.server.com/css/reports.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

in the header of your report.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to style reports via CSS. The accepted answer works but it may not be the most friendly for current and future developers. You can modify the existing global styles pretty easily, either via the existing classes or by adding your own. If you are looking at a per-report scenario, you can create local classes within the report itself rather than juggling multiple CSSs on the server.

[<del>I wrote a blog post on this awhile back with more detail</del>](http://therealtoddnappi.blogspot.com/2013/05/cognos-ways-to-apply-object-styles.html) (404, blog was removed).